# Запись значения переменной PHP в textarea

Tags: php, html

Всем привет, ситуация такова. На форме присутствуют две формы: первая для поиска в бд, вторая для изменения данных в бд.

Логика такая, что введя данные в первую форму, при нажатие на кнопку отправляется запрос, который ищет инфу по введенным данным и расписывает их по переменным в PHP. После чего, значения этих переменных необходимо вывести в 3 штуки textarea второй формы присутствующей на странице.

Не могу понять, как вывести значение переменной.

HTML

```
<form action="/php/find.php" id="find-form" method="post">

        <label for="kab">Кабинет:</label>
        <input type="text" name="kab" placeholder="Введите кабинет" id="kab" >
        <input type="submit" name="find-sub" id="find-sub" value="Найти">      
    </form> 
    <form action="/php/update.php" method="post" id="update-form">  
        <label id='info_about_kab'>Информация о кабинете:</label>
        <label for="name">Название кабинета:</label>

        <!-- пытаюсь вот так -->
        <textarea name="name" id="name" cols="30" rows="4">
            <?php
                include "php/find.php";
                print_r($name);
            ?>
        </textarea>

        <label for="tehn">Техническое обеспечение</label>
        <textarea name="tehn" id="" cols="30" rows="10">

            </textarea>


        <label for="po">Программное обеспечение:</label>
        <textarea name="po" id="kab_po" cols="30" rows="10" class="form_output">

        </textarea>
        <div><br><br>  

        <input type="submit" name="update-sub" id="update-sub" value="Изменить данные">
        </div> 
    </form>
```

php

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

$nom = filter_var(trim($_POST['kab']),
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if (isset($_POST['find-sub'])) {
    $find_kab="SELECT * FROM `classroom` where `class_numb`='$nom'";
    $find=mysqli_query($mysqli, $find_kab);
    $info_about_classroom = mysqli_fetch_assoc($find);
    $row_cnt = $find->num_rows;

    if ($row_cnt == 0) {
        echo "Кабинет не найден. Пожалуйста, один из предложенных кабинетов: 11, 15, 21, 28, 36, 37, 46, 47. <a href='../input.php'>Return</a>";
        exit();
    } else {
        $name = $info_about_classroom['name'];
        header('Location: ../input.php');
    }
}

?>
```

Переменную выводил, данные заносятся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено.

```
  <form action="" id="find-form" method="post">

        <label for="kab">Кабинет:</label>
        <input type="text" name="kab" placeholder="Введите номер кабинет" id="kab">
        <input type="submit" name="find-sub" id="find-sub" value="Найти">
        <?php
            include "php/connect.php";<!--connection to db  -->

            $nom = filter_var(trim($_POST['kab']),
            FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            <!-- button click check -->
            if (isset($_POST['find-sub'])) {
                $find_kab="SELECT * FROM `classroom` where `class_numb`='$nom'";
                $find=mysqli_query($mysqli, $find_kab);
                $info_about_classroom = mysqli_fetch_assoc($find);
                $row_cnt = $find->num_rows;
                <!-- verification -->
                if ($row_cnt == 0) {
                    echo "<br> <div 
                                style='color:white;
                                font-size:27px; 
                                border-radius:15px;
                                float:left;
                                padding: 2%;
                                width: 98%;
                                border: 1px solid silver;
                                line-height: 120%;
                                background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.95);'>
                        Ошибка. <br> <br>Кабинет не найден. Пожалуйста,
                        введите один из предложенных кабинетов:<br> 11,<br> 15,<br> 21,<br>
                        28,<br> 36,<br> 37,<br> 46,<br> 47.</div>";
                    exit();
 <!-- record to variables -->
                } else {
                    $name = $info_about_classroom['name'];
                    $tehn = $info_about_classroom['tehn'];
                    $po = $info_about_classroom['softwear'];
                }}                
        ?>      
    </form> 

        <form action="/php/update.php" method="post" id="update-form">  
            <div style='width: 98%; border: 1px solid silver; padding: 1%; background-color: rgba(39, 30, 73, 0.95); float:left; border-radius:15px'>
                <label id='info_about_kab'>Информация о кабинете №<?php include "php/connect.php";
                print_r ($nom)?> </label>
            </div>
            <input name="numb" id="numb" type='hidden' value='<?php include "php/connect.php";
                print_r ($nom) ?>'>
            <label for="name">Название кабинета:</label>

            <textarea name="name" id="name" cols="30" rows="7"><?php include "php/connect.php";
                print_r ($name) ?></textarea>

            <label for="tehn">Техническое обеспечение</label>
            <textarea name="tehn" id="" cols="30" rows="10"><?php include "php/connect.php";
                print_r ($tehn) ?></textarea>


            <label for="po">Программное обеспечение:</label>
            <textarea name="po" id="kab_po" cols="30" rows="10" class="form_output"><?php include "php/connect.php";
                print_r ($po) ?></textarea>
            <div><br><br>  

            <input type="submit" name="update-sub" id="update-sub" value="Изменить данные">
            </div> 
        </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```php
<textarea value="<?php echo $name?>" name="po" id="kab_po" cols="30" rows="10" class="form_output">
```

Comment: ничего не изменилось

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: как по мне, проблема в том, что обновляется страница, и при обращение к скрипту с выборкой информации значение переменной стирается, поэтому я думаю, что нужно как-то из php скрипта переадресацию сделать без изменения данных, но как, я не знаю, тк новичок. UPD: Разделил одну страницу на две, на каждой странице по одной форме.

Comment: Тут главное условие, что РНР должен отработать ДО отрисовки станицы, чтобы подготовить переменные, поэтому в коде РНР должен быть выше HTML

Comment: И тогда строка `header('Location: ../input.php');` не нужна

Comment: @DrMcSheen, честно, не пойму логики работы такой программы, скрипт, считывающий значение из input и передающий его значение в условие выборки, должен сработать до того, как страница загрузится и в этом input`e появится какая-либо информация? Если что-то из Вашего комментария не так понял, тогда нужно поподробнее